# Interprocess file system communication without sockets

Tags: python, ipc, message-queue, named-pipes

I'm running a network emulator called *MiniNet Wifi* that allows for emulating network topologies including APs and UEs (hence the wifi). The emulation software is the only process that can access some key variables, e.g. '*in range APs*' of an UE (i.e. mobile device).

The UEs and APs are running in seperate linux network namespaces (*netns*). The emulation is running in the host (regular) namespace. This means that no communication between the host and device network stack is possible. And this is also how I need it to be, for unrelated reasons.

Long story short, I need to spawn a thread in the emulation process that will allow other processes to pass messages (to and from). Thus I need to use the file system and not the network stack. So my question boils down to what the 'best' way of doing this in python is. Named pipes, just a simple file etc?

What also could be mentioned is that its ideal if the message passing is rather quick (ish) since the tasks are somewhat time critical.

Thanks.

Ps. Everything is obviously running on the same physical machine and share file system, i.e. not to be confused with docker.

Comment: I realize that this is more of a operating systems question, but surely there has to be a 'preferred' way of doing this in python.

Comment: Named (UNIX) sockets will be fine - pipes are probably less useful. A simple file + mmap is probably faster (and an anonymous mmap/shmem segment might be faster), but you have to figure out the synchronisation protocol yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Useless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212858/useless) for pointing me in the right direction. I found [this link](http://www.velvetcache.org/2010/06/14/python-unix-sockets) and it solves my problem perfectly!